# what's the point using www-data for user and group?

Tags: server, permissions, users

if this has been asked before I apologize.

Usually the advice for setting file permission in wordpress are folder `750` and file `640` with user and group `www-data`. Based on my understanding if user and group is the same then if somehow outsider can access using `www-data` he still can read or write,right?

so what's the point on setting up users and group as `www-data` ? Is there security reason for this ? I think if file / folder is set as user other than `www-data` then the owner permission can be useful.

Comment: It's the typical dilemma with how web servers usually work: If you want convenience (config/updates/uploads over web) it usually needs to be able to write somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's for flexibility. You could add other users to the www-data group and those users could do whatever is permitted by the group flags (which need not necessarily be the same as the user flags).